# How do I check Permissions while my PhoneGap App is running?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I have a Phonegap/Cordova app where the user needs to allow access to things like album or camera.

Assume you request the permission for camera on app start an the user denies. How can I check during the running app I the user gave the permission or not?

**Is there a way to check if the app has the required permissions from within the app?**

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml

You can check the permissions of your app by going to your Android Settings -> Apps -> App Name

Running adb logcat while the application is running would help you identify permission related errors

Comment: Please read my question. I want to read the permission after the app in running!